# Conditional formatting formula to highlight appropriate date in range

Tags: sql, excel

I need a formula for conditional formatting that will highlight a date between A2:Z2 which matches a number that I enter into a “Committed Sessions Cell” (A1).  In row 2 there are a series of numbers that appear above each date column (1,2.3, etc).  For example, if I enter a “3” in cell A1, the date in J3 should match the number 3 above it and be highlighted.  The idea here is to provide a quick visual prompt for how many sessions are in a client’s contract.

Note:  the sequenced numbers 1,2,3 etc in row 2 appear every 5th column (with nothing in between) but there IS other data in between the dates in row 3.  Only the appropriate date should be highlighted.

```
       A  B  C  D   E  F  G   H  I  J  K  L   M     

1      3
2      1            2               3                                           
3.     1/2/14       2/3/14          2/15/14
```

With grateful thanks,

~ Jay

Comment: Postscript:  Cell A1 (Committed Sessions) is located elsewhere on my sheet, not where it is shown here.  Row 2 is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not consistent.  If you have the date every fifth column, the dates should be in columns A,F,K,P, etc. with 4 columns between 2 points.

I came up with the following formula: =AND(A2=$A$1,MOD(COLUMN(A3)-1,5)=0) which is applicable to the entire 3rd row.  Create it as follow:

1. **IMPORTANT: Select cell A3** (the reference point for the formula)
2. Without selecting another cell, highlight the entire row 3
3. Go to Conditional Formatting -> New rule
4. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. In "Format values where this formula is true", put =AND(A2=$A$1,MOD(COLUMN(A3)-1,5)=0)
6. Choose the formatting that you want (example: Fill with yellow)
7. Click OK all the way

**NOTES**:

1. To change the location of your Committed Sessions, change $A$1 to another cell.  Important to keep the dollar signs
2. The MOD function is the one that controls every fifth column.  If you want the highlight every 4th column (i.e. 3 cells between each point such as A, E, I, etc.), replace the number 5 with the number 4

Comment: Actually, I should have clarified that in the above example, the first date is in A3, the second in E3 and the third in J3.  Oops, you're right.  There's only 3 empty spaces between A3 & E3 - should be four.

Comment: I tried working with your solution just now and discovered that I couldn't select a cell A2 and then highlight row 3 without losing my initial selection.  Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I learned how to select both A2 and highlight row 3.  However, when I went to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use formula to determine which cell to highlight > entered your rule and applied a color fill format, it simply filled cell A2 and highlighted every 5th cell in row 3.   Again, what I need is for A1 to be the controlling cell.  If I type a 2 in A1, then the second date in row 3 should be highlighted (in above example, "2/3/14")

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake.  I meant to say **"A3"** in the instruction.  If you see the formula, it refers to relative cell reference A3 and A2.  When you create the conditional formula for the entire row, Excel uses the formula of the selected cell (A3) and copy it across the whole row.  The formula for B3, for example will have B2 and B3 (keeping $A$1 unchanged).  The formula for C3 will have C2 and C3 reference, and so on.  That's the way Excel copies non-conditional formula as well.  Again sorry for the mistake.